# Passing text from one textBox to another in a same form using C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to do something very simple ( at least I do think so). I have a Form with a `Split Container` and each part (they are two at all) has only a `textBox` and the idea is while I'm writing at textBox1 to visualize this text at `textBox2`. I figure out how to pass some data from the one box to the other but I don't know how to get the value of the `textBox` and pass it to the other. An again I want to mention that the 2 textBoxes are in one form, so it should be a pretty easy task I suppose. 
  Here is my code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //how to get the text from textBox1?
            textBox2.AppendText("I want to pass the text form textBox1");
        }
    }
```

And also, I'm using `Visual Studio 2010`.

Comment: Do you mean you want the text to appear in `TextBox2` as you type in `TextBox1`?

Comment: Yes, `Paul Alan Taylor's` answer is exactly what I meant/need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it as simple as:-

```
textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
```

?

Answer (score 4):

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                
            textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 `private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //how to get the text from textBox1?
            textBox2 = textBox1.Text;
        }`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the text from textbox1
use this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //how to get the text from textBox1?
            textBox2 = textBox1.Text;
        }
```

but if you want to add the text from textbox1 to textbox2
use this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
            //how to get the text from textBox1?
            textBox2.AppendText(textbox1.text);
        }
```